# PostgreSQL returns dashes (-) for "select * from pg_stat_statements" when DB is under stress

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a stress test on my back-end. My PostgreSQL is working and functioning.

However when doing in PSQL

```
select * from pg_stat_statements order by max_exec_time desc limit 10;
```

I get:

```
emplyeees_db=# select * from pg_stat_statements order by max_exec_time desc limit 10;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:...skipping...
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[ RECORD 1 ]-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why can't I see any results? What are those dashes?

Comment: Did you read the log to find errors when executing this query ?

Comment: @SQLpro: I have no logs relating to any errors from PG.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when the query text file has grown too large for Postgres to load.

Try issuing pg_stat_statements_reset() before the benchmark to see if that helps (this will reset all stats, and clear the query text file).